# add hash to wordpress wp_listcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, categories

Is it possible to append # to

```
wp_list_categories( 'include=13&title_li=&style=none&echo=0')?
```

In  final link categories link need to look like: `domain/categories/somepost#`

Comment: You can either copy WP's function (wp-includes/category-template.php, line 417) and add the hash, or use append it with JS on DOMReady.

Comment: @konzepz dont understand where to copy wp function?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a filter for the output of wp_list_categories could do this in the php.
You would need to use preg_replace and a regex for finding the urls. 
For example:

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'filter_categories', 10, 2);
```

to add your "filter_categories" function to the filter - don't call it filter categories, call it something unique like sjn_filter_categories.

```
function filter_categories($output, $args=array()){
      return preg_replace('/(\<a\shref=\"?[^\>]+?)\"/', '$1#"', $output);
}
```

Will take the output, search it for href urls, remove the '"' and add '#' and '"' back on.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Look complicated for me :-(
Ill be happy to help me